# DynamoDB not seeing API Version? (ruby AWS-SDK)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been struggling with this for over a day now. All the documentation for this is completely wack, the examples don't work, etc. Really frustrated for something that should be so easy.

All I'm trying to do is make a sample table. I'm using the DynamoDB Local Test tool.

This is what I have, so far. And I get... `unexpected option attribute_definitions`

```
ddb = AWS::DynamoDB::Client.new(:api_version => '2012-08-10')

ddb.create_table({
  :attribute_definitions => [
    {
      :attribute_name => "id", 
      :attribute_type => "S"
    },
    {
      :attribute_name => "range",
      :attribute_type => "S"
    }
  ],
  :table_name => "actions", 
  :key_schema => [
    {
      :attribute_name => "id",
      :key_type =>       "HASH"
    },
    {
      :attribute_name => "range",
      :key_type =>       "RANGE"
    }
  ],
  :provisioned_throughput => {
    :read_capacity_units  =>  1,
    :write_capacity_units => 1
  }
})
```

The only thing I can think of is it's not seeing the API version properly, as 'attribute_definitions' didn't exist in the 2011 API version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was solved by using aws-sdk version 1.24.0.  I am working on a ruby app using dynamodb session store.  aws-sdk was locked at 1.11.1.  The problem was corrected with 'bundle update aws-sdk'to bundle aws-sdk version 1.24.0.